# Is it necessary to use throw keyword with Throwables.propagate(e)?

Tags: java, exception, guava

In this code, do I need the `throw` keyword in order to propagate the exception?

```
try {
  //try something
} catch (Exception e) {
  throw Throwables.propagate(e);
}
```

The `Throwables` documentation says that this method always throws an exception - is adding the `throw` superfluous? Could I have written the following instead?

```
try {
  //try something
} catch (Exception e) {
  Throwables.propagate(e);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [javadoc](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/base/Throwables.html#propagate(java.lang.Throwable)) also states

> The `RuntimeException` return type is only for client code to make Java
>   type system happy in case a return value is required by the enclosing
>   method.

and then provides this example

```
T doSomething() {
  try {
    return someMethodThatCouldThrowAnything();
  } catch (IKnowWhatToDoWithThisException e) {
    return handle(e);
  } catch (Throwable t) {
    throw Throwables.propagate(t);
  }
}
```

In other words, the return type (`RuntimeException`) is necessary so you can use the method in `return` or `throws` statements.

In the above example, if you omitted the `throw` in the last `catch` block, then the Java compiler would report an error because it cannot guarantee that a value will be returned from that `catch` block. [A `return` or `throws` instead indicate that the method completes at that point, abruptly.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.17)